# Calculate the Time complexity

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

$T(n)=\sqrt{2T(n-1)}$
what will be the time complexity if $T(n)$ is given as this?
I tried substitution but no result was reached.

Comment: I'm curious about how you get this recursive relation. Note changing the time unit would invalidate this relation.

Comment: Note that this isn't a question about time complexity: it's a question about solving recurrence relations. Perhaps the function $T$ does denote the running time of some algorithm, but that doesn't actually matter, for your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: You are asking to solve a recurrence; it has nothing to do with "time complexity" beyond maybe where the recurrence came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the initial value. For example, if $T(0) = 2$ then you can prove by induction that $T(n) = 2$ for all $n$. More generally, let $S(n) = T(n)/2$. Then
$$
S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2T(n-1)}}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{T(n-1)}{2}} = \sqrt{S(n-1)}.
$$
Simple induction now shows that $S(n) = \sqrt[2^n]{S(0)}$, and so
$$ T(n) = 2 \sqrt[2^n]{\frac{T(0)}{2}}. $$
In particular, this shows that $T(n) \to 2$.

We can estimate the speed of convergence using the estimate
$$
\sqrt[2^n]{x} = \exp \frac{\log x}{2^n} = 1 + O\left(\frac{\log x}{2^n}\right).
$$
This shows that
$$ T(n) = 2 + O(2^{-n}). $$

Answer (score 0):

With substitution, we will get $T(n) = \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{2}}}}$ with length $n$. Now, suppose $n$ goes to $\infty $, we will have $A = \sqrt{2A}$. Therefore, $A^2-2A = 0$ and $A = 2$. Hence, $T(n)$ would be constant as $T(n)$ is increasing. And we can write $T(n) =\Theta(1)$.

Comment: While I agree with your final answer, it seems like there is a gap in the justification here.  It appears that you are implicitly assuming that there exists a constant $c$ such that $T(n) \to c$ as $n \to \infty$.  Of course, if that is true then $T(n) = \Theta(1)$.  However, while that assumption is in fact true, you never provided any evidence for that assumption.  How do you know that there isn't some possible value for $T(0)$ that makes this sequence increasing, or eventually increasing?  I think we need to prove that $T(n+1) < T(n)$ if $T(n)>2$, or something like that.